# ActionBarSherlock, use fragmentTabPager effect without tabs

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

im using [actionbarsherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/index.html), so i want to take the fragmentTabPager effect with out the ugly tabs. Insted i want to use ActionBar.tab that is use in demo sample. 
For me fragment is quite hard to fully understand so i need some help with code, tutorial or whatever can help me out.

What i pretend, is like google+ app action bar under profile.

Is this possible to merge both samples?

if is necessarily, just sample code. Where do i put that fragment effect here?

```
setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock); //Used for theme switching in samples
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.tab_navigation);
    mSelected = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

    getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        ActionBar.Tab tab = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
        tab.setText("Tab " + i);
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        getSupportActionBar().addTab(tab);
    }
```

Regards.

Comment: There are numerous fully sourced examples all around the web and even YouTube. You should try searching Google and Stackoverflow for some, then come back here with a specific programming question.

Comment: didnt found out this on starkoverflow, maybe u can show me a link to it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to plug my own website too much, but I believe I can help you a great deal with this. I've worked with ABS and actionbartabs/viewpager for the last month or two. Having had such a pain with it (sounds like you're going through what I did), I decided to put up a tutorial or two about it on my site. So far it's helped a couple people (they emailed me for questions etc).

Here's the tutorial that I laid out: http://davidjkelley.net/?p=34

There are a couple other ones related to it as well, but I don't want to spam link and upset people. Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: thx for the response dave. i can see if i can use this with actionsherlok.

Comment: You definitely can :p I don't know about WITHOUT the ActionBar tabs, but my app uses ABS, TabsAdapter, ViewPager, basically everything it looks like you need :P